# django south - got messed everything up - how do I start over?

Tags: database, django, django-south

I like south a lot and it's cute and all but I again got everything messed up somehow. I've looked at all the questions and answers on this and I have only progressed so far as from "table already exists" to "no such table" errors.

Is there a way to reset everything and start over with clean db and south to save some nerve and hair? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the database and run:

```
python manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

South has its own tables that are added during syncdb.

Comment: This has worked, thanks a lot. I had to rm migrations/ though for that to work. How do I get back to south now? :)

Comment: Probably shouldn't have done that. If there was a problem migrating, you should have fixed the migration, not deleted the whole folder. You might be able to get by with just the initial migration (run `python manage.py schemamigration --initial [app]`, but if you had any datamigrations, you'll have to rewrite those now.

Answer (score -1):

You could just drop the database and then run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: ...no such table south_migrationhistory